# Activar un plugin en función de otro

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo un problema con 2 plugins.

Lo que necesito es que si intento activar "Plugin 2" y esta activo "Plugin 1", no lo active y muestre un mensaje y viceversa.

Este es el código del Plugin 1:

```
function plugin_revisar()
{
    if ( ! function_exists( 'is_plugin_active' ) )
        require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
    
   //Compruebo si está activo el plugin 2
    if (is_plugin_active('plugin_2/main.php')) {

        plugin_error_activar();
        // Desactivar el plugin en caso de existir activa otra versión del plugin
        deactivate_plugins(plugin_basename(__FILE__));
    }

}
add_action('admin_init', 'plugin_revisar');
/*
 *  Mensaje de error en caso de existir activa otra versión del plugin
 */
function plugin_error_activar()
{
    $clase = 'notice notice-error'; // Cargar el formato de error de WP
    $mensaje = "Está activada otra versión del plugin 2";
    printf('<style>.wp-core-ui .notice.is-dismissible {display: none;}</style>');
    printf('<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr($clase), esc_html($mensaje));
}



register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_activacion' );
 
function plugin_activacion() {
  ..tareas a realizar
}

register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'plugin_eliminacion');

function plugin_eliminacion() {
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_desactivacion' );

function plugin_desactivacion() {
}
```

Este es el código del Plugin 2:

```
function plugin_revisar_2()
{
    if ( ! function_exists( 'is_plugin_active' ) )
        require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
   //Compruebo si está activo el plugin 1
    if (is_plugin_active('plugin_1/main.php')) {

        plugin_error_activar_2();
        // Desactivar el plugin en caso de existir activa otra versión del plugin
        deactivate_plugins(plugin_basename(__FILE__));
    }

}
add_action('admin_init', 'plugin_revisar_2');
/*
 *  Mensaje de error en caso de existir activa otra versión del plugin
 */
function plugin_error_activar_2()
{
    $clase = 'notice notice-error'; // Cargar el formato de error de WP
    $mensaje = "Está activada otra versión del plugin 1";
    printf('<style>.wp-core-ui .notice.is-dismissible {display: none;}</style>');
    printf('<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr($clase), esc_html($mensaje));
}



register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_activacion_2' );

function plugin_activacion_2() {
  ..tareas a realizar
}

register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'plugin_eliminacion_2');

function plugin_eliminacion_2() {
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_desactivacion_2' );

function plugin_desactivacion_2() {
}
```

Teniendo los dos plugins desactivados

Activo plugin 1 -> OK

Desactivo plugin 1

Activo plugin 2 -> OK

### Y ahora el problema

Si tengo activo el plugin 1 y quiero activar el plugin 2, me desactiva el plugin 1, activa el plugin 2 y me muestra el mensaje del plugin 1.

Sin embargo, si tengo activo el plugin 2 y quiero activar el plugin 1, no me lo activa y me muestra el mensaje del plugin 1 . Realiza la función correcta.

¿Alguna idea por que ocurre esto?

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado poniendo en el `add_action` en vez de `admin_init` he puesto `activate_plugin`.

Y quitando la llamada a `deactivate_plugins` sustituyéndola por `wp_die(plugin_error_activar_2())`, la que corresponda en cada plugin.

Realizado en los dos plugins.

Salu2